# Comparing a probability to Chebyshev's Theorem.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am a little confused with this questions I was assigned. For the experiment, flip a coin until heads shows, assume that the probability on heads on one flip is `$$\frac{3/4}$$`. We define a RV X = the number of flips. The probability distribution function for X I calculated was p(X=x) = 3/4(1/4)^x-1.

1) What is the expected number of flips? My result: 4/3

2) What is the standard deviation of the number of flips until heads shows? 
My result: 2/3

3) Compute the probability P(4/3-2/3 < x < 4/3+2/3) and compare to what Chebyshev's Theorem says it should be. My result (for first half): .33438

Comment: We get that the probability is $\ge 0$. Chebyshev never lies, it *really is* $\ge 0$.

Comment: How can I compute Chevyshev's? What is the variable k in the formula 1-1/k^2?

Comment: Here $k=1$. In my answer, I quoted the $\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge \sigma k)$ version of the Inequality.

Comment: Okay but why does k = 1? I'm sorry just trying to understand it.

Comment: We want the probability that $X$ is within $2/3$ of the mean. The standard deviation is $2/3$, so we are asking for the probability of being within $1$ *standard deviation unit* of the mean, that is, $k=1$ in the inequality. By the way, I don't think the actual probability is the one you give. For being within $2/3$ of $4/3$ means that $2/3\lt X\lt 6/3$, which is only possible when $X=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The Chebyshev Inequality, [Wikipedia version,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)  tells us that for any positive real $k$,
$$\Pr\left(\left|X-\mu\right|\ge \sigma k\right)\le \frac{1}{k^2}.$$
Taking $\mu=\frac{4}{3}$, $\sigma=\frac{2}{3}$ and $k=1$, we find that
$$\Pr\left(\left|X-\frac{4}{3}\right|\ge \frac{2}{3}\right)\le \frac{1}{1^2}.$$
So the inequality  tells us that
$$\Pr\left(\left|X-\frac{4}{3}\right|\lt \frac{2}{3}\right)\le \frac{1}{1^2}\ge 0.$$
 Not an impressive estimate! The Wikipedia article remarks that the inequality is not useful if $k\le 1$.